# query an array field using MongoDB to find documents matching substrings of multiple values

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I hold recipes in a database, each recipe has ingredients field of type `Array`. to the query i pass an array of ingredients for example:
`["banana", "apple", "watermelon"]` , and i want to find all recipes in the db containing in the ingredients field each of the ingredients passed to the query. the issue is the ingredients passed to the query are usually substrings of the ingredients in the DB, so for example a document in the DB can have "1 ripe banana" in its ingredients array and in the query i pass "banana" , which mean this document should be returned has a result. the result documents should include each of the ingredients passed.

i did manage to find all recipes including **at least** one using this 
    code:

```
app.get('/recipe', (req, res) => {
if (req.query.ingredients) {
    let ingredientMap = req.query.ingredients.map(x =>
    Recipe.find({ingredients: {$regex: new RegExp(JSON.parse(x).name)}}));

    return Promise.all(ingredientMap).then((results) => {
        if (!results) {
        res.status(404).send();
    }
    let filteredResults = results.filter(x => {
        return typeof x !== 'undefined' ? x[0] : null
    });

    let merged = [].concat.apply([], filteredResults);

    res.status(200).send(merged);
    }).catch( e => {
        res.status(400).send();
    })
}

});
```

but how can i make a query where each result includes all of the ingredients passed to the query, as substrings?

Comment: The `.name` of an ingredient is a plain string, right? Odd, it [looks like](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) you're doing it exactly as you should be

Comment: yes, like `"banana"` for example, which means array of strings

Comment: @CertainPerformance he can't use the `$all` since the issue is he wants substrings. `$all` would have worked if his recipes ware composed of "clean" ingredients but he has `1 awesome bag of bananas`  and he searches for `banana`. Hence the need for the `$regex` etc.

Comment: not sure i understood, if none found the result is empty

Comment: Makes sense @yarivbar see if the proposed answer would work for you and makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in a different way with a change to your regular expression.

Loop through your array from `req.query.ingredients` (for example `["banana", "apple", "watermelon"]`) and compose this regEx:

`(?=.*banana)(?=.*apple)(?=.*watermelon).+`

Something among these lines:

```js
const ing = ["banana", "apple", "watermelon"]
const result = `${ing.reduce((r,c) => r.concat(`(?=.*${c})`), "")}.+`
console.log(result)
```

This is using positive lookahead and would match if all of the ingredients are found in your recipe. This should also remove the need to use `Promise.all` since you would only need one mongoDB `find` query.

You can test the [regEx here](https://regex101.com/r/biAoOF/1)

Also make sure you do case-insensitive search with mongo via the [`$options`](http://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex):

```
{'$regex' : '<YOUR-REGEX>', '$options' : 'i'}
```

Otherwise if someone is really `BANANAS` about the ingredients in one of your recipes ... you wont find it :)

Comment: You might consider leading the regex with a start-of-string anchor (so that it fails faster if there's no match), and you can probably omit the trailing `.+`